# How to assign JSON string to a variable?

Tags: json, typescript, angular6

I'm trying send form input data to REST SERVICE.
Here the Present format is

```
{
  "locationname":"test",
  "locationtype":"test",
  "address":"test"
}
```

but service accepting format is

```
 {
    "value": "{ locationname: test ,locationtype: test, address:test }",
 }
```

tried to convert string with below

```
const tests = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(Form.value));
```

but how to assign to **Value**

I expect the result after form submit

```
{
  "value":"{ locationname: test ,locationtype: test, address:test }",
}
```

Comment: `const tests = JSON.stringify({ value : JSON.stringify(Form.value) });`

Comment: @ Pranav C Balan Assign to value is done but parameters are still in string format 
{

    "value":"{ "locationname": "test" ,"locationtype": "test", "address":"test" }",

}

Comment: if you need  an object with property value as JSON string then use `const tests = { value : JSON.stringify(Form.value) };`

Comment: It is sending as [object object]

Comment: your requirement is unclear

Comment: share complete code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

maybe this fits your requirement.
The "modifiedJsonObject" should be what you need to submit.

```
const formValue = JSON.parse('{"locationname":"test","locationtype":"test","address":"test"}');
    const formValueString = JSON
      .stringify(formValue)
      .replace(/"/g, '');
    const modifiedJsonObject = { value: formValueString };
    const jsonString = JSON.stringify(modifiedJsonObject);

    // jsonString = '{"value":"{locationname:test,locationtype:test,address:test}"}'
```

Comment: How to print values in html , end point giving response as ["id": 1, '{"value":"{name:test,type:test,address:test}"}' , "id":2, '{"value":"{name:test1,type:test1,address:test1}"}'];

Comment: First the given response represents an array of elements. Also it isn't a valid json. So you have to parse the whole string and get the string representing the value.